# How to evaluate a variable with two words in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

```
top
set /p alt=      
echo %alt%>>123.txt    
if %alt% equ *ex* goto ex   
goto top
:ex  
exit
```

I need to echo something from a batch file to a .txt file.
The problem I am facing is when I put two words or numbers or letters with spaces between them the program crashes. Can someone tell me what is causing it to crash and how to correct it.

```
*ex* is for exiting.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` syntax is `if somestring operator anotherstring dosomething`.

The most common operator is `==`, and to `dosomething` then two strings must **exactly** match.

To group strings containing separators such as spaces, `"enclose the strings in double-quotes"`

Hence

```
if "%alt%" equ "ex" goto ex
```

should work for you (it's unclear whether you intended to include the asterisks in the string - if so, the match is **literal**, so the asterisks will **not** means "any characters")

```
if /i ....
```

will make the comparison case-insensitive.

Comment: I do want to include the asterisks in the strings

Answer (score 1):

If `*` should be taken *literally* in the `*ex*` string:

```
:top
set /p alt=      
echo %alt%>>123.txt    
if "%alt%" equ "*ex*" goto :ex   
goto :top
:ex  
exit
```

If you do mean `*` as a kind of *wildcard* character (like in `dir *.txt`):

```
if NOT "%alt:ex=%" equ "%alt%" goto :ex
```

[Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html): Use the syntax below to edit and replace the characters assigned to a string variable.

> Syntax
>
> ```
>   %variable:StrToFind=NewStr%
> ```
>
> Key
>
> - `StrToFind` : The characters we are looking for;
> - `NewStr`    : The chars to replace with (if any);
> - `variable`  : The environment variable.

Next example shows case insensitivity:

```
-->echo "%OS%" == "%OS:kuk=%" ## "%OS:S_nt=%"

"Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" ## "Window"

-->echo "%ProgramFiles%" == "%ProgramFiles:ex=%" ## "%ProgramFiles:AM fi=%"

"C:\Program Files" == "C:\Program Files" ## "C:\Progrles"
```